Inverted colors of vector drawable
When I start the app some of my vector assets have the value of wrong color. If I start the app in light mode the vectors use the dark mode colors.
If the dark mode is turned on and then off then vectors use normal colors (from light mode)
my drawable resource
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="460dp"
    android:height="265dp"
    android:viewportWidth="460"
    android:viewportHeight="270">
  <path
      android:pathData="M139.85,137.51C155.15,142.34 170.44,165.68 170.44,181.78C170.44,197.88 170.44,212.37 170.44,230.08C170.44,247.79 154.34,262.28 136.63,262.28C118.92,262.28 51.3,262.28 35.2,262.28C19.1,262.28 3,247.79 3,231.69C3,215.59 3,197.88 3,181.78C3,165.68 14.79,147.5 33.59,137.51M139.85,137.51C102.02,176.95 57.74,164.07 33.59,137.51M139.85,137.51C147.1,127.85 155.93,111.63 155.95,93.23C155.99,55 122.14,24 86.72,24C51.3,24 17.45,55 17.49,93.23C17.51,111.63 22.1,124.2 33.59,137.51"
      android:strokeWidth="20"
      android:strokeColor="@color/black"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M280.85,116.5C243.02,155.95 198.74,143.07 174.59,116.5M280.85,116.5C288.1,106.85 296.93,90.63 296.95,72.23C296.99,34 263.14,3 227.72,3C192.3,3 158.45,34 158.49,72.23C158.51,90.63 163.1,103.2 174.59,116.5M280.85,116.5C291.13,119.75 301.4,131.35 307.04,143.5M176.2,241.28C192.3,241.28 259.92,241.28 277.63,241.28C281.01,241.28 284.34,240.75 287.5,239.77M176.2,241.28C173.61,241.28 171.02,240.9 168.5,240.21C171.44,240.94 173.12,241.24 176.2,241.28ZM174.59,116.5C162.97,122.69 154.02,131.99 148.89,142"
      android:strokeWidth="20"
      android:strokeColor="@color/black"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M422.85,137.51C438.15,142.34 453.44,165.68 453.44,181.78C453.44,197.88 453.44,212.37 453.44,230.08C453.44,247.79 437.34,262.28 419.63,262.28C401.92,262.28 334.3,262.28 318.2,262.28C302.1,262.28 286,247.79 286,231.69C286,215.59 286,197.88 286,181.78C286,165.68 297.79,147.5 316.59,137.51M422.85,137.51C385.02,176.95 340.74,164.07 316.59,137.51M422.85,137.51C430.1,127.85 438.93,111.63 438.95,93.23C438.99,55 405.14,24 369.72,24C334.3,24 300.45,55 300.49,93.23C300.51,111.63 305.1,124.2 316.59,137.51"
      android:strokeWidth="20"
      android:strokeColor="@color/black"/>
</vector>

my collors.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <color name="black">#D9D9D9</color>
</resources>

bottom_navigation_menu
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/HomepageActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/FollowingActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_following"
        android:title="" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/AllChatsActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ProfileActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="" />
</menu>

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:hideOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/foreground"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

This is what I am expecting

and this is what I am getting as result

I tried using
android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"

but it did not help

Can we assume it's the @drawable/ic_following (the people icon) as the one identified with the issue.

yes, that is the one
